# How to count total number of values as they appear inside a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table called Sales. And i have a field called plate_number corresponding to a single car.

How can i find the total number of instances of each car in db.

E.g `[ [plate_number1, 10 times found], [plate_number2, 5 times found] ]`

I tried using

`Sale.map(&:plate_number).count`
and
`Sale.pluck(:plate_number)`

but these just do a simple count of that column

any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `count` with `group` like:

```
Sale.group(:plate_number).count
```

This will return a hash with each `plate_number` and the count of occurrences.

```
# => { 'plate1' => 5, 'plate2' => 2 }
```

Comment: when I try User.group(:name) it gives ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function, but it is working with count. can you please explain?

Comment: this is when User.group(:name) sql: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" GROUP BY "users"."name", and when User.group(:name).count sql: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, "users"."name" AS users_name FROM "users" GROUP BY "users"."name"

Comment: when you use `group` you have to do something with the fields that are not grouped by, you need to define an operation like a `maximum, minimum, count, average` you can check the docs at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group

Comment: I have not post this question actually, its posted by @petros, I just come in between :)

Comment: hey thanks this worked great, marked it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a second solution i found for anyone who is interested

```
Sale.all.group_by { |ss| ss["plate_number"] }.map { |k,v| [k, v.length] }
```